# How to consolidate Django (different models) database and store at centralized place

Tags: django, linux, database, django-models, devops

I have created a Django-based webpage where different vendor company employees can logins and can change their Shift Timing. (Now we are controlling this job with Linux script but due to large user size ~8k doing it for all requests is a difficult task).
To resolve this I have created a Django webpage( 6 separate models/DB) and used default SQLite DB.

Requirement:
The user is working on some application which needs to be controlled by updated shift timing on the portal.

**Question:**

1. How to consolidate OR store DB data in a centralized place? so that if tomorrow I have to reset the Timing for all the users in the portal to default consider General Shift.
   I have the below Idea to do this but not sure if this is the best way to complete this work.
2. by using the REST API I will get the JSON data.**OR**

   manage.py dumpdata apple.CompanyName(Model) --indent 5

any help/Suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the database u could use an  Hosted db like heroku postgres database, If ur new
to database else u can  run ur own postgres database in the server.AS u mention there 8k its not good to use SQLite DB  as it  is  file system based.To update the shift timing u can use the default Django admin. I am not sure about ur model  structure but as  long as you have necessary validation in  logic it can be  updated  from admin anytime